# In href, ~ is not working when binding from code behind

Tags: asp.net

When binding href tag from code behind it's not working. This is my aspx code. When I am directly putting `<a>` tag on aspx it's working whereas as soon as I doing it through Response.write it's reading ~ as such not as a root directory.

```
<% Response.Write("<a id=\"A1\" runat=\"server\" class=\"menuItem\" href=\"~/HR/Emp/EmpDetails.aspx?mid=167\">My PIPs</a> "); %> 

<a id="A1" runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~/HR/Emp/EmpDetails.aspx?mid=167">My PIPs</a>
```

binding through literal also it's not working

```
Literal.text = "<a id=\"A1\" runat=\"server\" class=\"menuItem\" href=\"~/HR/Emp/EmpDetails.aspx?mid=167\">My PIPs</a> ";
```

Please help on this.

```
these are the HTML tags
<ul id="jMenu">
    <li>
      <a  runat="server" class="fNiv" href="~\Default.aspx?mid=1&">Home</a> 
      </li>
    <li>
      <a  runat="server" class="fNiv" href="">Human Resources</a> 
    <ul>
      <li class="arrow" /> 
       <li>
      <a runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\HR\EMP\PIPWorkFlow.aspx?mid=166">Performance Improvement Plan (PIP)</a> 
    <ul>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\HR\EMP\PIPWorkFlow.aspx?mid=171">Data Protection Statement</a> 
      </li>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\HR\EMP\EmpPIPDetails.aspx?mid=167">My PIPs</a> 
      </li>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\HR\EMP\PIPHome.aspx?mid=168">Team PIPs</a> 
      </li>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\HR\EMP\HRPIPHistory.aspx?mid=169">Employee PIPs</a> 
      </li>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\HR\EMP\AppraisalRatingUpload.aspx?mid=170">Upload Appraisal Ratings</a> 
      </li>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\HR\EMP\PIPRoleAssignment.aspx?mid=472">PIP Spoc Role Assignment</a> 
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" class="fNiv" href="~\ContactUs.aspx?mid=39">Contact Us</a> 
      </li>
      </ul>
```

these are the html tags... if we are binding these tags with Literal or div or TD ... they are reading ~ sign as such...
if I am putting these tags directly in HTML its working perfectly fine

Comment: pls provide full code..

Comment: Showing the code you are talking about would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Response.Write` and `Literal.Text` output whatever you give them with no processing.

This means whatever you give these methods/property will be output verbatim. No URL resolution will occur and the `runat=server` attribute is meaningless.

You can use the [`Control.ResolveClientUrl()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) to generate the link yourself, or manipulate the link as a server control in the codebehind.

**Option 1**

```
// this line is fine
string url = ResolveClientUrl("~/some-url/foo.aspx");

// this line is quite ugly, but should work
var lit = new Literal { Text = "<a href='" + url + "'>a link</a>" };

// add it the page/control's control hierarchy
this.Controls.Add( lit );
```

**Option 2**

```
// instantiate the control dynamically
// URL resolution is done automatically
var lnk = new HtmlAnchor { HRef = "~/some-url/foo.aspx" };

// add it the page/control's control hierarchy
this.Controls.Add( lnk );
```

**Option 3**

Let's say that you must deal with a string, not the control hierarchy (as per the comments). This is not ideal, but it is possible if the URLs in the string are relative to the application root.

```
// resolve the application root
string root = ResolveClientUrl("~/");

// string of raw HTML
string html = "<a href=\"~/HR/Emp/EmpDetails.aspx?mid=167\">My PIPs</a>";

// replace the urls with a resolved version
// this is very simplistic...a proper parser would be more reliable
html = html.Replace( "~/", root + "/" );

// output as desired
Response.Write( html );
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Actually this Html content is dynamically coming from XSLT. We are using JMenu for database driven menus. After XSLT into HTML tags... href is not working <a> tag

Comment: Does your HTML have the `~/` in it from the XSLT? Or are you adding that later?

Comment: Gettting these html tags from XSLT transformation <li>
  <a id="A18" runat="server" class="menuItem" href="~\Training\Report\RBTReport.aspx?mid=88">RBT Report</a> 
  </li>

Comment: ~/ coming from xslt... we are not adding it later

Comment: Okay. One solution (kind of ugly) is to resolve `~/` and then do a find/replace on your string with the updated URLs. Give me a second and I'll add an example of doing that.

Comment: done the same but its working on Local... but on UAT on virtual directory its not working

Comment: The find/replace solution will only work if the raw HTML has a path that is relative to the application, since `~/` resolves to the root of the application. You might want to look at the paths being output to the page; it may give you a clue to the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim... Its working fine now... On our local we were having IIS7 and on UAT IIS6... thats why it was not working on UAT... Thanks a lot for your precious time and help...